# Execution failed for task ':app:lintVitalRelease'. Flutter

Tags: flutter, gradle

Why I get these errors I try to release apk

I run "flutter build apk --release"

Execution failed for task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.
[image: :app:lintVitalRelease]
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android_intent'.

> - What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring root project 'android_intent'.
>
> > SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.

android/app/build.gradle

```
def localProperties = new Properties() def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties') if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    } }

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk') if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with  flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.") }

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode') if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1' }

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName') if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0' }

apply plugin: 'com.android.application' apply plugin: 'kotlin-android' apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.deleviry"

   minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    } }

flutter {
    source '../..' }

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.0'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version" }

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

android/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    } }

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    } }

rootProject.buildDir = '../build' subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}" } subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app') }

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir }
```

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Upgrading gradle build tools seems to break some lints.

To fix this you can:

> If your error says debug/libs.jar, build --debug then --release. 
> If your error says profile/libs.jar, build --profile then --release.

from https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/58247#issuecomment-636500680

If the above doesn't work you can disable the check.

Add `checkReleaseBuilds false` in `lintOptions` in the **android/app/build.gradle** file.

```
android {
    ...
    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
        checkReleaseBuilds false //<- add this line
    }
}
```

Comment: this disables the check ! so it's not performed, and the underlying problem isn't fixed !

Answer (score 7):

If your error says `debug/libs.jar`, build `--debug` then `--release`:

```
flutter build apk --debug
flutter build apk --release
```

If your error says `profile/libs.jar`, build `--profile` then `--release`:

```
flutter build apk --profile
flutter build apk --release
```

Taken from [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/58247#issuecomment-636500680)

Comment: Hi, it works thanks! But just wondering, does it solve the fundamental issue?

Answer (score 2):

If you're having this issue and you can't fix it with either fixes like me, you might be having different flavors. I had to run the run and run --release command for every flavor before I could build one without an error.

so
flutter run --flavor dev
... (do so for every flavor)
flutter run --flavor lastFlavor
then
flutter build apk --flavor dev (error)
... (do so for every flavor)
flutter build apk --flavor lastFlavor (SUCCESS!)

and from now on you can build every flavor without error :)

Answer (score 0):

I've stuck to the latest Android Studio Gradle plugin from the `3.x` series (`3.6.4`) paired with an up-to-date Gradle version (AS plugin `3.6.4` + Gradle `6.6` yields no error for me).

*Edit: As of today July 13th 2021, Flutter 2.2.3 runs fine with Android Studio Gradle plugin version 4.2.2 and Gradle 6.8.3 (stable)*

Comment: how do u upgrade gradle plugin

Comment: In Android Studio, under "Project Structure", you can pick the Android Studio Gradle plugin to suit your needs.

Comment: where i can get Gradle 6.8.4 (stable) ?, i check on gradle release, lastest release for 6.8.x is 6.8.3 
https://gradle.org/releases/

Comment: You are absolutely correct Septiyan, it was my mistake. Gradle `stable` 6.x tops at 6.8.3; I've corrected the post.

Comment: i',m try using AGP 4.2.2 and gradle 6.8.3 still issue when building with flavor, so for now i still use AGP 3.5.4 and gradle 6.8.3 , or add `checkReleaseBuilds false `

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the correct way, but I solved similar issue by adding these lines

```
release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            shrinkResources false // Add this line 
            minifyEnabled false // Also add this line
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case, this part of the code was absent in android/app/build.gradle so i added it and it worked.

```
  lintOptions {
    disable 'InvalidPackage'
    checkReleaseBuilds false 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue by adding classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.1" in android>build.gradle dependecies. It worked perfectly.

Note: my gradle wrapper version was https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4.2-all.zip in gradle-wrapper.properties

Basically this problem occurred some of dependencies uses latest gradle version and your project version is different.

Answer (score 0):

lintOptions {
disable 'InvalidPackage'
checkReleaseBuilds false //<- add this line
}

add this code will solve your problem