# Execution failed for task ':url_launcher:createFullJarDebug' java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException

Tags: android, flutter, debugging

I am trying to build an app to publish an update to the playstore.
I am facing following issue in debug mode and observe that while running
`flutter run --release` works fine.

**Error in DEBUG mode**

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':url_launcher:createFullJarDebug'.
>
> > java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: .../flutter_app/build/url_launcher/intermediates/library_java_res/debug/res.jar

I have tried:

`flutter clean`
`flutter pub cache clear`
`./gradlew clean`

multiple times.

Switched Flutter channel from `stable` to `master` and checked same error.

I was developing the app before the `Flutter 2.0` and now I am facing this error.
I update `url_launcher` to latest version as well but **all in vain**.

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile writing this issue, I came across this [hint from @dennismayr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63384877/4669744). So, I updated my gradle plugin from `3.5.0` to `4.1.0` *(By looking at my other apps in development using same flutter sdk/channel)* and *voila!* the app launched fine in debug mode.

Anyway, I am pasting the case here. Might be of help if someone else face the same issue.