# Flutter Execution failed for task ':app:lintVitalRelease'

Tags: flutter, gradle, apk

I am trying to build release apk with 'flutter build apk --release' command but gives this error. How can I fix this?[image]

Comment: checkout this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62548438/execution-failed-for-task-applintvitalrelease-flutter

Comment: its not work for me.

Comment: Please do not post text in screen shots. Text in images is hard to read and in your case it is even truncated. You can simply copy everything to clipboard and then paste it as cos into your question.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed problem.

Adding this line to 'gradle.properties' file, will fix your problem:

> android.jetifier.blacklist=bcprov-jdk15on